# Stream audio file

Tags: javascript, playframework

So I am trying to stream and download audio file to the browser.
My files are stored on a seperate drive to the web application.
Currently I am using java to send the file:

```
public static Result recording(Long id) {
    PhoneCall currentCall = PhoneCall.getCall(id);
    if (currentCall != null) {
        File wavFile = new File("D:\\audio\\"
                        + currentCall.fileName);
        return ok(wavFile);
    } else {
        return badRequest();
    }
}
```

This works fine in that i can stream the audio and it plays nicely. And I am playing the audio through a html5 element.
But I am trying to use a slider control and using audio.currentTime to set the current time so a user can play midway through but it seems that I cannot set this value. I also cannot get the duration of the audio file using audio.duration.

Even when i use `<audio controls="controls"` it does not allow me to play midway through

Is there something I am missing? Can I get javascript to download the whole file before it starts playing so that i can get all this information? Or is there another way to send this using play framework?